# Postgres - new role with SELECT shows empty table, whereas superuser role shows data in same table

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

thank for taking the time to try answer/understand this question.

I am using AWS Aurora Postgres (Engine version: 13.4) database.
I referred to [this document](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/) for creating `readwrite` and `readonly` roles for 2 new `rdsiam` users -> "dev_ro" and "dev_rw". I have granted `readwrite` role to "dev_rw" and `readonly` to "dev_ro". The additional changes are:

1. `myschema` is "public" - which is my default schema
2. I add the same permissions as "myschema" to another schema called "graphile_worker" (from [graphile/worker](https://github.com/graphile/worker) - which is a job queue).

With this in mind, here is what I have done:

1. I run my application which adds some repeating jobs (jobs schedule itself), implying that the `jobs` table can never be empty
2. Connect to RDS using the IAM user (doesn't matter dev_ro or dev_rw)
3. I run `SELECT * FROM graphile_worker.jobs` in my IDE (dbeaver - shouldn't matter, I think)
4. The table shows up empty
5. Disconnect and Re-connect to RDS using superuser credentials (which are created when server is created)
6. Run same query as above
7. See data in the table

I don't know why this is happening.
I double-checked, both "dev_ro/w" (through the roles) and superuser, have:

- `CONNECT` to database (without doubt)
- `SELECT` on all tables of `graphile_worker` schema
- `USAGE` on the `graphile_worker` schema
- Moreover, I can query `graphile_worker.migrations` and the migration records show up as expected (on both devro/w and superuser)!

Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide to help debug this issue.

Comment: Can you include the DDL for the table?  Do you have row-level security?

Comment: @Hambone The DDL is here -> https://github.com/graphile/worker/blob/main/__tests__/schema.sql#L5-L23.
And if you scroll to bottom, the table has row-level security.

Comment: @Ashniu123 Can you share the connection string you are using to connect graphile worker to postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Row-Level Security (RLS) solved this issue.
Thanks @Hambone for asking the right question.

RLS is removed by executing

```sql
ALTER ROLE <username> WITH BYPASSRLS
```